# How to control text box multiple lines in vb 2017

Tags: vb.net

I want display two lines in text box. Example calculator, Here I type the calculation values are show in first line and Answer is shown second line. How?

Comment: Multiline = True

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by setting the property of the TextBox:

```
Multiline = True
```

To add multiple line in a text, for example, to show `2+2 = 4`

```
TextBox1.Text= "2+2=" & VbcrLf & "4"
```

This will show output as:

> 2+2=
>   4

`VbcrLf` breaks the line and let you write in the next line

Answer (score 0):

Use a richtextbox

```
Richtextbox.Appendline("2+2=" + vbNewLine + "4")
```